# Returning null as primitive type in Java works. Why?

Tags: java

why does `javac` for:

```
int xx() {
      return true ? null : 0;   
}
```

returns?

```
int xx();
   0: aconst_null
   1: checkcast     #2   // java/lang/Integer
   4: invokevirtual #3   // java/lang/Integer.intValue:()I
   7: ireturn
```

Note that my `xx` returns `int`- a primitive type. Why is `javac` disobedient and tries to return reference type - `Integer` (`java.lang.Integer.intValue()`)

Comment: It does not try to return reference type `Integer`. The result type of `intValue()` is a primitive `int`.

Comment: The more interesting question is why does the compiler optimize the ternary operator due to the `true` constant condition away and generate byte code that _must_ fail with an NPE. :)

Answer (score 3):

Java has the feature that instances of `java.lang.Integer` are automatically unboxed (by inserting a `Integer.intValue()` call).

If you try to return `null` in your method, the compiler thinks that you have a instance of `java.lang.Integer`. This `java.lang.Integer` is then unboxed and returned.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because of a feature called **Autoboxing.**

You are trying to return null - a primitive `int` can not have a value of null, but the class `Integer`, can. Java automatically boxes and unboxes between the primitives (`int,char,bool` and so on) and their classes (`Integer,Character,Boolean`) without your intervention, to accommodate reference type behavior .